# self.navigationController is returning nil (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code in my app delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = createInititalViewController()
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}

func createInititalViewController() ->  UINavigationController{

    var currentStocksModel = CurrentStocksModel()
    var currentStocksController = CurrentStocksViewController(model: currentStocksModel)

    var navController:UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: currentStocksController)

    return navController
}
```

When I println(self.navigationController) in the CurrentStocksViewController, it returns nil. What am I forgetting to do?

This is where I am calling my println()

```
init(model:CurrentStocksModel) {
    super.init()
    self.model = model

    stocksView = CurrentStocksView()
    stocksView.delegate = self
    self.view = stocksView

    println(self.navigationController)
}
```

Comment: Where exactly would that `println` code be?

Comment: Added code above :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you first create `CurrentStocksViewController` via `init` and after that you create `UINavigationController` with `currentStocksViewController`.

So, in the `init` method of `CurrentStocksViewController`, there is no `UINavigationController`. You should move the logic to `viewDidLoad`

Comment: The viewDidLoad method never gets called in my CurrentStocksViewController. Why is that?

Comment: When your view controller's view loaded `viewDidLoad` method gets called and views loaded lazily in cocoa touch. That means you need to add it into view hierarchy or manually call the viewController's `view` property.

Comment: Didn't I call my view controller's view property right here?: self.view = stocksView

Comment: You got it all wrong my friend. The `view` of the view controller comes from either a nib file (interface builder) or created manually in code. Assuming you want to create your `view` in code you need to do it in `loadView` method of `UIViewController`. Not in the init method. Just override `loadView` method and assign `self.view` to `CurrentStocksView` in there.

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware that that had to be done in the viewDidLoad method and not the init. It now returns not nil. Much appreciated!